# Python: How do I write a message to items in a list without printing each message individually?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python3, I'd like to write a blanket message that goes to all items in the list (names of dinner guests, in this case) without having to print each message individually.

For example, if the list is:

```
guest_list = ['John', 'Joe', 'Jack']
```

I want it to print this line below using each person's name without having to individually print the message 3 times:

```
print("Hello, " + *name of guest from the list above here* + "! We have found a bigger table!")
```

Desired Result:

```
Hello, John! We have found a bigger table! 
Hello, Joe! We have found a bigger table! 
Hello, Jack! We have found a bigger table!
```

Is this possible? If so, how? Thanks to any help offered!

Comment: add a for loop?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do only one `print`:

```
guest_list = ['John', 'Joe', 'Jack']
result_str = ['Hello {}! We have found a bigger table!'.format(guest) for guest in guest_list]
print(result_str.join('\n'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple for loop:

```
guest_list = ['John', 'Joe', 'Jack']
for x in guest_list:
    print("Hello, " + x + "! We have found a bigger table!")
```

> Hello, John! We have found a bigger table!
>
> Hello, Joe! We have found a bigger table!
>
> Hello, Jack! We have found a bigger table!

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following:

```
for x in guest_list:
    print("Hello, %s! We have found a bigger table!" %x)
```

Where %s allows you to insert a string format which is replaced by the variable I am passing to it.